# How to make spring batch to catch exception and continue with work without complete job?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to catch an exception in the item processor, do something and continue to work with the job without completing the job. And if it is possible with this to have JdbcPagingItemReader to avoid possible thread issue when reading.

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Slf4j
public class AppConfig {
private final ProcessorVerificationSkipper processorVerificationSkipper;
private final WriterVerificationSkipper writerVerificationSkipper;

private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
private final MyProcessor myProcessor;
private final MyWriter myWriter;

private final DataSource dataSource;

public AppConfig (
        JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
        StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
        MyProcessor myProcessor,
        MyWriter myWriter,
        DataSource dataSource,
        ProcessorVerificationSkipper processorVerificationSkipper,
        WriterVerificationSkipper writerVerificationSkipper) {
    this.processorVerificationSkipper = processorVerificationSkipper;
    this.writerVerificationSkipper = writerVerificationSkipper;
    this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
    this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
    this.myProcessor = myProcessor;
    this.myWriter= myWriter;
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}
/* Without pagination
@Bean
public ItemReader<MyTable> itemReader() {
    JdbcCursorItemReader contactJdbcCursorItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    contactJdbcCursorItemReader.setSql("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE");
    contactJdbcCursorItemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    contactJdbcCursorItemReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(MyTable.class));
    return contactJdbcCursorItemReader;
}*/

// with pagination
@Bean
public JdbcPagingItemReader<MyTable> itemReader() throws Exception {
    return new JdbcPagingItemReaderBuilder<Object>()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .saveState(false)
            .queryProvider(queryProvider())
            .rowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(MyTable.class))
            .pageSize(10)
            .fetchSize(10)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public PagingQueryProvider queryProvider() throws Exception {
    SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean provider = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
    provider.setDataSource(dataSource);
    provider.setSelectClause("SELECT *");
    provider.setFromClause("FROM MYTABLE");
    provider.setSortKey("ID");
    return (PagingQueryProvider)provider.getObject();
}
@Bean
TaskExecutor taskExecutorStepPush() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
    taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(4);
    taskExecutor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
    taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    return taskExecutor;
}

@Bean
public Step step() throws Exception {
    DefaultTransactionAttribute attribute = new DefaultTransactionAttribute();
    attribute.setPropagationBehavior(Propagation.REQUIRED.value());
    attribute.setIsolationLevel(Isolation.READ_COMMITTED.value());
    //  return
    SimpleStepBuilder<MyTable, MyTable> builder =
            (SimpleStepBuilder<MyTable, MyTable>)stepBuilderFactory.get("stepName")
            .<MyTable, MyTable >chunk(10)
            .reader(itemReader())
            .processor(myProcessor)
            .faultTolerant()
            .skipLimit(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty(CHUNK_SIZE)))
            .skip(Exception.class)
            .skipPolicy(processorVerificationSkipper)
            .writer(myWriter)
            .faultTolerant()
            .skip(Exception.class)
            .skipPolicy(writerVerificationSkipper)
            .noRetry(Exception.class)
            .noRollback(Exception.class)
            .transactionAttribute(attribute);
    return builder.build();
}
```

ProcessorVerificationSkipper.java

```
@Component
public class ProcessorVerificationSkipper implements SkipPolicy {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkip(Throwable throwable, int i) throws SkipLimitExceededException {
    return true;
    }
}
```

WriterVerificationSkipper.java

```
@Component
public class WriterVerificationSkipper implements SkipPolicy {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkip(Throwable throwable, int i) throws SkipLimitExceededException {
    return true;
    }
}
```

MyTable.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity(name = "MYTABLE")
public class MyTable{
     @Id
     @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, precision = 0)
     private Long sourceId;
     @Basic
     @Column(name = "A", nullable = true, length = 10)
     private String a;
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
job.delay.fixed=120000
## Actuator When to show full health details.
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
## Actuator - Endpoint IDs that should be included or '*' for all.
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=shutdown,flyway

java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/MyDS
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.auto-commit=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

MyProcessor.java:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MyProcessor implements ItemProcessor<MyTable, MyTable> {
@Override
public Object process(MyTable myTable) {
    return doSomething(myTable);
  }
private Object doSomething(MyTable myTable) {
    try {
        myTable.setA("a");
        // do something
    }
    catch(Exception1 e) {
         myTable.setA("e1");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
         myTable.setA("e2");
    }
    return object;
  }
}
```

MyWriter.java

```
@Component
public class MyWriter implements ItemWriter<MyTable> {
private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;

public DocumentWriter(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate) {
    this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate = namedParameterJdbcTemplate;
}

@Override
public void write(List<? extends MyTable> list) {
    SqlParameterSource[] batch = SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(list.toArray());
    int[] updateCounts = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("UPDATE MYTABLE SET A = :a, batch);
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <oracle-ojdbc8.version>12.2.0.1</oracle-ojdbc8.version>
    <maven-jaxws-plugin.version>2.5</maven-jaxws-plugin.version>
    <maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>2.4</maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>
    <jupiter.version>5.5.0</jupiter.version>
    <mockito.version>2.23.0</mockito.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.1</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <maven-war-plugin.version>3.2.2</maven-war-plugin.version>
    <weblogic-wlclient.version>12.1.1</weblogic-wlclient.version>
    <lombok.version>1.16.20</lombok.version>
    <oracle-ojdbc.version>12.2.0.1</oracle-ojdbc.version>
    <appache.http-client.version>4.5.9</appache.http-client.version>
    <mockito.version>3.0.0</mockito.version>
 </properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.28</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${appache.http-client.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<profiles>

</profiles>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <classpathDependencyExcludes>
                    <classpathDependencyExcludes>ch.qos.logback:logback-classic</classpathDependencyExcludes>
                </classpathDependencyExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                        <Implementation-Vendor-Id>${project.groupId}</Implementation-Vendor-Id>
                        <Implementation-URL>${project.url}</Implementation-URL>
                        <Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalProperties>
                            <version>${project.version}(${build.number})</version>
                            <Implementation-Version>${project.version}(${build.number})</Implementation-Version>
                            <BuildNumber>${build.number}</BuildNumber>
                            <BuildURL>${build.url}</BuildURL>
                        </additionalProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>



</project>
```

With this when an exception occurs job finished as COMPLETED which I don't want. I want to go for all selected records to the end, no matter of exceptions, just to set the value of the property depending on the type of exception.

Is this possible?

How to configure a job?

Comment: `continue to work with the job without completing the job` how is that possible? You are catching all exceptions in your processor, so the job will continue with remaining records until completion. Do you mean if an exception occurs in the processor you want to continue with all remaining records but the job should finish with another status than COMPLETED?

Comment: That's what I want to know. Let say there are 10.000 records. And there is an exception in the first chunk. It will write not 10 but 1, then 1, and 2, and 2 again, then 5. It will take the next chunk, and one more and then it says it is COMPLETED (write only 32 items). And even my scheduler is 'fixedDelay' (2 minutes) it will start new job even previous one wasn't finished.
And yes, I want to job to continue with next chunk and next chunk and 1.000 times (chunk is 10) on 10.000 records, but job finished as COMPLETED.

Comment: According to your code, your job will be in status COMPLETED since you catch all exceptions. If you want to change the status, you need to get a handle to the job execution and change its status.

Comment: But why job stopped after 30 records when there are 9.970 records more to go?
And do I need skip and skip policy if I catch all exceptions in the processor without throwing them?

Comment: no you don't need it since you catch all exceptions. I didn't understand that your job stops before expected. Please provide a minimal reproducible example to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I put a code. Is it ok?